# How do I tell cmake which version of python to use?

Tags: python, cmake

I want to use use python 3.7 instead of python 2.7 when building with cmake.

This is the error I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81wAs.png)

How do I tell cmake which python to use?

Text version of my error -

-- Building local IBM Accelerator simulator.
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")
-- Found UUID: /usr/include
-- Found Python: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found version "2.7.17") found components: Interpreter Development
-- Found Python version 2.7.17. Version must be greater than 3.0.0, skipping Python API build.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/cades/dev/envs/xacc/build

Comment: What are you building with CMake? CMake itself does not use Python. You'll likely need to reference the documentation for the software you are trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a recent version of CMake and that you are developing the build system of the project you discussed above, you could do the following:

```
find_package (Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
```

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html#module:FindPython3

Now, if you are building an existing project, you would have to check if the project support using a newer version of python.